# How to deploy a smart contract to private network by EthereumJ?

Tags: java, ethereum, smartcontracts

I set up a private ethereum network by go-ethereum,and I configure the Ethereumj's config to connect to the private network,I can see the Ethereumj's information in go-ethereum's console:

```html
> admin.peers
[{
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "e084894a3b72e8a990710a8f84b2d6f99ac15c0a1d0d7f1a6510769633b64067f9c2df2074e920a4e46fc7d7eb1b211c06f189e5325f0856d326e32d87f49d20",
    name: "Ethereum(J)/v1.5.0/Windows/Dev/Java/Dev",
    network: {
      localAddress: "127.0.0.1:30303",
      remoteAddress: "127.0.0.1:18499"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 7746910281,
        head: "0x97568a8b38cce14776d5daee5169954f76007a79d7329f71e48c673e6e533215",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}]
>
```

then I run the sample of deploying contract(CreateContractSample.java)，and the go-ethereum is mining on the private network,but I get the output:

```html
14:10:37.969 INFO [sample]  [v] Available Eth nodes found.
14:10:37.969 INFO [sample]  Searching for peers to sync with...
14:10:40.970 INFO [sample]  [v] At least one sync peer found.
14:10:40.970 INFO [sample]  Current BEST block: #10105 (0fc0c0 <~ e6a78f) Txs:0, Unc: 0
14:10:40.970 INFO [sample]  Waiting for blocks start importing (may take a while)...
14:10:46.973 INFO [sample]  [v] Blocks import started.
14:10:46.973 INFO [sample]  Waiting for the whole blockchain sync (will take up to several hours for the whole chain)...
14:10:56.974 INFO [sample]  [v] Sync complete! The best block: #10109 (90766e <~ 46ebc3) Txs:0, Unc: 0
14:10:56.974 INFO [sample]  Compiling contract...
14:10:57.078 INFO [sample]  Sending contract to net and waiting for inclusion
cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826
14:10:57.093 INFO [sample]  <=== Sending transaction: TransactionData [hash=  nonce=00, gasPrice=104c533c00, gas=2dc6c0, receiveAddress=, sendAddress=cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826, value=, data=6060604052346000575b6096806100176000396000f300606060405263ffffffff60e060020a600035041663623845d88114602c5780636d4ce63c14603b575b6000565b3460005760396004356057565b005b3460005760456063565b60408051918252519081900360200190f35b60008054820190555b50565b6000545b905600a165627a7a72305820f4c00cf17626a18f19d4bb01d62482537e347bbc8c2ae2b0a464dbf1794f7c260029, signatureV=28, signatureR=33b12df9ac0351f1caa816161f5cc1dec30e288d97c02aedd3aafc59e9faafd1, signatureS=457954d2d34e88cdd022100dde72042c79e918ff6d5ddd372334a614a03a331a]
''''''some Unnecessary output''''''
java.lang.RuntimeException: The transaction was not included during last 16 blocks: ed2b6b59
at org.ethereum.samples.CreateContractSample.waitForTx(CreateContractSample.java:142)
at org.ethereum.samples.CreateContractSample.sendTxAndWait(CreateContractSample.java:116)
at org.ethereum.samples.CreateContractSample.onSyncDone(CreateContractSample.java:73)
at org.ethereum.samples.BasicSample.run(BasicSample.java:148)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to know the reason of this error.

Comment: First thing I see is that you're missing receiveAddress field. put a address here (without 0x)